# How do I install KDE in my Debian installation?

Tags: kde, debian-squeeze, kde-4

How do I install KDE in my Debian installation? I have a Debian Squeeze 6.0.7, which was installed from a DVD. I would like to install `kde-full` package into it.

How do I install KDE in my current installation?

My current status is:

1. Debian Squeeze 6.0.7
2. updated `sources.list` to include Wheezy main, for new kernel version 3.2
3. updated to the Wheezy kernel
4. 64-bit machine, with 64-bit Debian

How am I supposed to get a good working KDE desktop?

Answer (score 12):

**`$ sudo apt-get install kde-standard`**

That will install the standard KDE desktop as of Wheezy and Jessie.

Answer (score 3):

K Desktop Environment (KDE) is a free desktop environment and development platform built with Trolltech’s Qt toolkit. It runs on most Unix and Unix-like systems, such as Linux, BSD and Solaris. [install KDE in my Debian installation](http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html)

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
# aptitude --without-recommends install ~t^standard$ ~t^desktop$ ~t^kde-desktop$
```

Or install KDE from the default repositorie

```
# apt-get install kde-standard
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue - but I had to take a few steps back

- first, be sure your system can find the packages it needs

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list if you need to add the URL for the package repository for your flavor of Linux

- then refresh the list in apt-get

Apt-get update

- then check for the package you want

Apt-get search

- if the search returns your package, go ahead and install it

Answer (score 0):

For newer Debian versions (starting from Debian jessie upto sid), you can install the [task-kde-desktop](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=task-kde-desktop) package  :

```
$ sudo apt-get install task-kde-desktop
```

It installs `kde-standard` + `task-desktop` (xorg + xserver-xorg packages) + the display manager packages.